# How to structure layers and responsibilities in Spring application?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, architecture

I went through some articles, tutorials about creating application in Spring to get some information how to structure my standalone (not web) Spring application into layers.

**Situation** - my application will process some data and do some computation with it. Data will be stored and read from different data sources (PostgreSQL and RESTful API).

I have an idea how to structure my app:

- **Domain objects** (`com.example.domain`) - simple POJO classes like Product, Order, Customer etc.
- **Service layer** (`com.example.service`) - These classes will be processing business logic and will cooperate with controllers and DAO objects and will be implementation of some interfaces (ProductManager, OrderManager, ...).
- **DAO / repository layer** (`com.example.repository`) - interfaces (ProductDao, OrderDao) defining raw data operations. There will be implementation of these interfaces for particular data source (PostgreSQLProductDao etc.).

**Questions:**

1. Is this dividing correct, makes sense to you?
2. When I use another DAO implementation, should be this switch done without any affecting of service class? I am asking because data processing will be processed in different way due to another data structure. For example, when I use the same database (PostgreSQL) from our another project instance, and where data is stored in different form, I need to do different computation (call another method from DAO layer a do some another operations with data). Should it be done in service layer or in DAO layer? Should I have more service layer implementations for each of our projects and data sources?

For example: In one our PostgreSQL database there are customers, some of them don't have all information in its rows. So for this database I need to obtain these missing informations after customer is read from data source. And because, from my point of view, DAO should do only basic operations (like CRUDL) I am not sure if this should be done in DAO layer or service layer.

I read many articles but I haven't found clear answer to these questions. Thanks.

Comment: For a standalone application I would strongly suggest you look into [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) to bootstrap the application and [Spring IO](http://platform.spring.io/platform/) for your data processing. Avoid all XML like the plague. Your structure looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

This separation makes much sense.

One the goals of separation of data accessing code in dedicated layer is to solve the issue you are asking about. Service layer shouldn't care about where and how exactly customer is stored and how to get all needed fields correctly. This is responsibility of DAO.

So DAO implementation should take care of getting entity from underlying data source(s).

Comment: So do you mean that service layer should be only one and it is a responsibility of DAO implementations to provide all and fully qualified data to the service? What could be a proper use case in my situation to create another implementation of interface defining service?

Comment: I can't really say as it depends on what you application really do. It may be that you will only have single implementation of each service for *production code* and there nothing wrong about it. But you may need to create some simple implementation (think stub or dummy) of some service to be able to test other services based on it.